# Postgres sequence get last usage

Tags: postgresql, sequence

I have a database that has both sequenced correlated to table unique ids and "standalone" but having values.

I need to know which ones are really used but I'm not the owner of every procedure running on the database.

Is there any way to know when a Postgres sequence was last used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the time when a sequence is used is not recorded by PostgreSQL.

I would figure out the `last_value` of each sequence, wait for a week and do it again.  Then you can easily see which sequences have advanced and how much.

Comment: Thank you, I think I'll do so. Actually before asking I've looked all the db catalog without finding a timestamp, so just asking to see if I lost something but no way